# The volume obtained by rotating the region bounded by $y=\sqrt{81-(x-4)^2}$ and the $x\ -$ axis about the line $x=14$.

Tags: calculus, volume

> Question: The volume obtained by rotating the region bounded by $y=\sqrt{81-(x-4)^2}$ and the $x\ -$ axis about the line $x=14$.

I used both Disk and cylindrical shells method to evaluate the volume. Using **Cylindrical Shells :** Here the expression will be $V=\int_{-5}^{13} 2\pi\ (14-x)\sqrt{81-(x-4)^2} \ dx=810\pi^2$. Using **Disk mehod :** we have $\int_{0}^{9} \pi\ ((-10-\sqrt{81-y^2})^2-(\sqrt{81-y^2}-10)^2)\ dx= \int_{0}^{9}40 \pi \sqrt{81-y^2} \ dy=810 \pi^2$.

The answer is $405 \pi$. Please correct me. Thanks.

Comment: I think you've missed the $x=0$ part...

Comment: Please make it more clear to me. @DS

Comment: quick integration (I may have made an error) shows me that $810\pi^2$ is the volume after you rotate the full semicircle, but the question asks for "the region bounded by $y = \sqrt{81-(x-4)^2}$ and **the x-axis** "

Comment: That region is half the torus$$\left\{(x,y,z)\in\Bbb R^3\,\middle|\,\left(\sqrt{(x-14)^2+y^2}-10\right)^2+z^2=81\right\},$$whose volume is $2\pi^2\times10\times81=1620\pi^2$. So, the answer has to be $810\pi^2$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos what about my previous comment? Shouldn't the red part be revolved around the green part - https://i.stack.imgur.com/IuqMn.png

Comment: @DS You are right. I missed that reference to the $x$-axis.

Comment: I tried integrating the required part using cylindrical shells. I am not able to get $410 \pi$

Comment: @AasthaChoudhary can you disclose the source of this problem?

Comment: The question was asked in my test. What is your answer?@DS

Comment: numerically, something around $1620 \pi$...

Comment: @DS Thanks for confirming your answer, I will try again.

Comment: @AasthaChoudhary it is best to ask your professor about it.

Answer (score 1):

Where are you getting the $\pi^2$? 
Notice that the shape is half donut since y cannot be negative. Also, in disk method there should be dy in the first integration.
The shape for your reference:[image]

Comment: there is also $x = 0$ part

Comment: What according to you should the limits be? @quantinho